# area of a helix

Tags: area

is anyone knows how to calculate the area of a ring that is twisted, for example an edge of a tooth of a thread coil, please see a picture (area between A and B points)

[image]

Comment: $d$ and $D$ would not be sufficient to compute the area. You also need the pitch of the helix surface.

Comment: thread as an example i need to know an area of the ring if i know both diameters and an angle or a height, the picture on the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the area of a right circular conical frustum, the lateral surface area is equal to

$$\pi(d+D)\sqrt{(D-d)^2+h^2}$$

where $d,D$ are the two diameters and $h$ the height. See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum) for more details.

Comment: appreciated, that was i was looking for thanks